Can someone help me work through an example of finding a $C^1$ isometric embedding per Nash?
I believe Nash's method of applying "corrections" to a "short" embedding is modernly referred to as convex integration. I've been reading Nash's original paper where he details his proof and method of being able to always find a $C^1$ embedding for any Riemannian surface but I'm not able to pick up on his notation. His paper is here.
I'm interested in 2-D surfaces embedded in 3-D space. If I have some embedding given either parametrically by Euclidean coordinates $x(\theta, \phi), \ y(\theta,\phi), \ z(\theta,\phi)$ or maybe some implicit function $r(\theta,\phi)=0$, I can obviously induce a metric. How can I make it "short", just by rescaling? Also, how do I choose weight-functions for neighborhoods on my surface?
If someone could detail the process in a simple way that'd be great..

It’s not easy to write an explicit formula. You can see examples here: https://hevea-project.fr/ENPageToreDossierDePresse.html
